# Como pasar de un caracter a valor ASCII sin usar las funciones ord o chr en Python

Tags: python, string, formato, ascii

Necesito pasar un carácter(String) a valor ASCII sin utilizar las funciones ord y chr.
tipo:

```
"a"=97
"b"=98
```

mi objetivo es que dependiendo de cada letra, recorra una cierta cantidad de espacios en un archivo de texto con un ciclo for en Python

ejemplo
si la letra es `a` recorro 4 si la letra es `b` recorro 8 si la letra es `c` recorro 12 espacios y así sucesivamente

sabiendo que `a` tiene codigo ASCII 97 puedo determinar que letra es con un ciclo for que recorra desde el 97 al 122 y asi comparando que letra es, y dependiendo del índice en que este el ciclo for, hago la multiplicacion por 4 que seria la constante de cuantos saltos doy

```
Ejemplo 
Letra d = 100 Valor ASCII
97+1+1+1 (se trasforma este valor a caracter para comparar con la "d") , índice en ciclo for = 3 , 3*4 = 12 espacios
```

Pensaba hacer un arreglo con todo el abcdario o la opcion de if=="letra" pero estos 2  serian demasiado  largo   serian mi ultima opcion

Se agradece cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Un par de soluciones sencillas:

- Tener una cadena con todas las letras minúsculas (de hecho tienes una predefinida en el módulo `string`) y buscar en ella la letra dada, usando el método `.index()`. Al índice retornado sumarle el ascii de la `a`. Por si necesitas convertir también mayúsculas puedes aplicar el mismo método teniendo la cadena con las mayúsculas y sumando 65 (ascii de "A")
- Construir un diccionario en el que las claves sean las letras y los valores sean los códigos. Esto puede ser más rápido para luego hacer la conversión de letra a código.

Veamos ejemplos de de ambos enfoques. Usando la búsqueda con `.index()`:

```py
import string

minusculas = string.ascii_lowercase   # O si prefieres pones "abcde...z" que es lo mismo
mayusculas = string.ascii_uppercase   # "ABCDE...Z"

def letra_a_codigo(letra):
   if letra in minusculas:
       return minusculas.index(letra) + 97
   if letra in mayusculas:
       return mayusculas.index(letra) + 65

print(letra_a_codigo('d'))
# Resultado: 100
```

Usando el diccionario:

```py
# Primero construimos el diccionario (uno solo en que habrá
# tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas)

codigos  = { letra: indice + 97 for indice, letra in enumerate(minusculas) }
codigos.update({ letra: indice + 65 for indice, letra in enumerate(mayusculas) })

def letra_a_codigo(letra):
   return codigos.get(letra)
```

Por cualquiera de los métodos, tal como están definidas las funciones `letra_a_codigo()`, si le pasas una letra que no está ni entre las mayúsculas ni entre las minúsculas (por ejemplo una "ñ" o un símbolo como "+"), el resultado devuelto por la función será `None`. Tenlo en cuenta o cámbialo si lo necesitas.

#### Rendimiento

He hecho un par de pruebas, convirtiendo todas las letras de un texto de 1687000 caracteres (entre los que hay muchos que no son letras) y cronometrado lo que tarda cada enfoque.

- El primer método tarda unos 418 ms en terminar
- El segundo con el diccionario tarda 290 ms

Como ves el método con diccionario es más rápido, pero la verdad es que yo esperaba que fuese *espectacularmente* más rápido (cientos de veces), pues los diccionarios son casi instantáneos en sus búsquedas, a diferencia de `.index()` que debe examinar todos los elementos. Sin embargo no llega ni a dividir por dos el tiempo necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución es convertir la letra a byte, y de ahí a entero. Estrictamente hablando, no hay una conversión, sólo una reinterpretación de los datos.

La función `convert` recibe una letra y retorna su valor numérico.

```
def convert(letra_ascii):
    x=letra_ascii.encode()
    return int.from_bytes(x, byteorder="big")
```

**Demo**

```
for letra in "abcdefg":
    print(f"Letra {letra} = {convert(letra)}")
```

produce:

```
Letra a = 97
Letra b = 98
Letra c = 99
Letra d = 100
Letra e = 101
Letra f = 102
Letra g = 103
```